# Play mp3 file in the resource with QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt, resources, qmediaplayer

I try to play mp3 files declared in the resource, but it show:

```
Btn clicked
current media: "qrc://sound/sound/FarAway.mp3"
Error :  QMediaPlayer::FormatError
Media state :  QMediaPlayer::InvalidMedia
```

Here's how I set media:

```
player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
player->setMedia(QUrl(mediaFilePath)); 
qDebug() << "current media: " << player->currentMedia().canonicalUrl().toString();

connect(player, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QMediaPlayer::State)), SLOT(handleStateChanged(QMediaPlayer::State)));
connect(player, SIGNAL(mediaStatusChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)), SLOT(handleMediaStateChanged(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus)));
connect(player, SIGNAL(error(QMediaPlayer::Error)), SLOT(handleError(QMediaPlayer::Error)));
```

According to [this post](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/26136) it said `QMediaPlayer` need to be called `play()` after the callback of `mediaStatusChanged()`, which is what I've done exactly. So what's the problem???

P.S. I could play the mp3 file from the [QMediaPlayer Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimediawidgets-player-example.html) as local file.

UPDATE 1: I can play the mp3 file as local file...

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is now no longer a problem, you can play a Qt resource in the QMediaPlayer. Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30085625/353094), and I'm confirming it here in case people are looking.

This code works for me when testing in my local project.

```
player->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/audio/audio/Revival_Song01.mp3"));
```

Comment: removing the "fromLocalFile" from Qurl fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

You should play a file from disk; not a Qt resource. Since the resources are not supported yet. You can copy the file from resource to your hard drive on the fly and then play it :

```
QFile::copy(":/files/FarAway.mp3" , "/some/path/FarAway.mp3");
```

Comment: I see some said packaging those mp3 files into the bundle like this=> http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/212415-playing-mp3-using-QMediaPlayer-API/page2
Tried without success, what's the right way to do it?