# Using a resource file in QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt5, qmediaplayer

How do I load a .mp3 file to use in a `QMediaPlayer` from a .qrc resource file?

This is what I have so far

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/audio/theme.mp3"));
player->play();
```

resources.qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/audio">
        <file>theme.mp3</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

theme.mp3 is located in the project directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play mp3 file in the resource with QMediaPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377720/play-mp3-file-in-the-resource-with-qmediaplayer)

Answer (score 20):

Use `m_player->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/audio/theme.mp3"));`

If you are using Qt Creator, you can copy this url to clipboard by pressing right button on the audio file in the side bar and choosing `Copy url "..."`.

Comment: I'm also having no sound (Qt 5.5) when I try to play from a resource. If I copy the file to a local file, then it works fine.

Comment: Great answer! thank you! And remember to remove `::fromLocalFile` when add `qrc:` to the path.